# Detecting a set of numbers in a column

Tags: excel

[image: Picture]

I have a set of numbers. (12,22,13) and (10,5,17). In column A, the cells can have any value. The column C outputs true if the next cell below is from the same set of numbers.

I used the formula

```
=IF(
     OR(
         AND( NOT(ISNA(MATCH(A1,{12,22,13},0))),
              NOT(ISNA(MATCH(A2,{12,22,13},0)))
            ),
         AND( NOT(ISNA(MATCH(A1,{17,10,5},0))),
              NOT(ISNA(MATCH(A2,{17,10,5},0)))
            )
       ),"true", "false"
   )
```

However I need it to output true if a number from the set of numbers is entered subsequently. In this case, C4 should output true because in cell A8, 12 is in the same group as 22 in cell A4. Also C7 should be false because cell A9 which is 10 is in the same group as 17 in cell a 7.

Comment: Having read this several times, I'm baffled about what you are asking Excel to do for you. The last two sentences seem to contradict each other. Are you saying that if a cell in row _m_ of column A has a number in the set and any row _n_ where _n > m_ has a cell in the set, then column C row _m_ should be true? (Or to say it another way, the only time C would be false for a number in the set is the last appearance of that number in A.) I'm so confused.

Comment: I am confused too, `A4`(22) belongs to set1 (12,22,13) and its next value `A5`(5) belongs to set2, so it should be `FALSE` per your statement: "The column C outputs true if the next cell below is from the **same** set of numbers", or is the condition that the next number should belong to any set (not the same as you said) regardless of the previous value belongs to set1 or set2? Why do you consider `A8` that is not the value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had someone help figure it out. I was able to use `=COUNT(FILTER(A8:A$30,ISNUMBER(MATCH(A8:A$30,IF(OR(A7={12,22,13}),{12,22,13},IF(OR(A7={2,4,0}),{2,4,0},{17,5,10})),0)),""))>0` and it worked swell